# PyQt - How to connect multiple signals to the same widget

Tags: python, pyqt4

```
[ ]All1           [ ]All2        

[ ]checkbox1A     [ ]checkbox1B

[ ]checkbox2A     [ ]checkbox2B
```

Based on the chart above, a few things need to happen:

1. The All checkboxes only affect the on/off of the column it resides in, and checks on/off all the checkboxes in that column.
2. All checkboxes work in pairs, so if checkbox1A is on/off, checkbox1B needs to be on/off
3. If an All checkbox is checked on, and then the user proceeds to check off one or more checkbox in the column, the All checkbox should be unchecked, but all the checkboxes that are already checked should remain checked.

So really this is more like a chain reaction setup. If checkbox All1 is on, then chieckbox1A and 2A will be on, and because they are on, checkbox1B and 2B are also on, but checkbox All2 remains off. I tried hooking up the signals based on this logic, but only the paired logic works 100%. The All checkbox logic only works 50% of the time, and not accurately, and there's no way for me to turn off the All checkbox without turning all already checked checkboxes off.

Really really need help ... T-T

Sample code:

```
cbPairKeys = cbPairs.keys()
    for key in cbPairKeys:
        cbOne = cbPairs[key][0][0]
        cbTwo = cbPairs[key][1][0]
        cbOne.stateChanged.connect(self.syncCB)
        cbTwo.stateChanged.connect(self.syncCB)

def syncCB(self):               
    pairKeys = cbPairs.keys()
    for keys in pairKeys:
        cbOne = cbPairs[keys][0][0]
        cbOneAllCB = cbPairs[keys][0][4]
        cbTwo = cbPairs[keys][1][0]
        cbTwoAllCB = cbPairs[keys][1][4]

        if self.sender() == cbOne:
            if cbOne.isChecked() or cbTwoAllCB.isChecked():
                cbTwo.setChecked(True)
            else:
                cbTwo.setChecked(False)
        else:
            if cbTwo.isChecked() or cbOneAllCB.isChecked():
                cbOne.setChecked(True)
            else:
                cbOne.setChecked(False)
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to user Avaris's help and patience, I was able to reduce the code down to something much cleaner and works 100% of the time on the 1st and 2nd desired behavior:

```
#Connect checkbox pairs     
cbPairKeys = cbPairs.keys()
    for key in cbPairKeys:
        cbOne = cbPairs[key][0][0]
        cbTwo = cbPairs[key][1][0]
        cbOne.toggled.connect(cbTwo.setChecked)
        cbTwo.toggled.connect(cbOne.setChecked) 

#Connect allCB and allRO signals    
cbsKeys = allCBList.keys()
    for keys in cbsKeys:
        for checkbox in allCBList[keys]:
            keys.toggled.connect(checkbox.setChecked)
```

Only need help on turning off the All checkbox when the user selectively turns off the modular checkboxes now

Comment: And where is your code? You should provide a small, self-contained example showing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your data structure, I have a solution. Correct me if I'm wrong: `allCBList` is a `dict` (confusing name! :) ). Its keys are the `all*` checkboxes. And a value `allCBList[key]` is a `list` with checkboxes associated with that `all` checkbox. For your example structure it'll be something like this:

```
{ All1 : [checkbox1A, checkbox1B],
  All2 : [checkbox2A, checkbox2B]}
```

Then what you need to is this: when a checkbox is toggled and it is in `checked` state, then you need to check the `All*` checkbox if all the other checkboxes are in `checked` state. Otherwise it will be unchecked.

```
for key, checkboxes in allCBList.iteritems():
    for checkbox in checkboxes:
        checkbox.toggled.connect(lambda checked, checkboxes=checkboxes, key=key: key.setChecked(checked and all(checkbox.isChecked() for checkbox in checkboxes))
```

I guess, this statement requires a bit of explanation:

```
lambda checked, checkboxes=checkboxes, key=key:
```

`lambda` creates the callable that is connected to the signal. `toggled` passes checkbox status, and it will be passed to `checked` variable. `checkboxes=checkboxes` and `key=key` parts pass the current values to `checkboxes` and `key` parameters of the lambda. (You need this because of the closure in `lambda`s)

Next comes:

```
key.setChecked(...)
```

We are setting the `checked` state of `key` which is the appropriate `All*` checkbox. And inside this:

```
checked and all(checkbox.isChecked() for checkbox in checkboxes)
```

`all` is `True` if everything inside is `True`, where we check every `checkbox`s state. And this will return `True` if all are `checked` (i.e. `isChecked()` returns `True`).

`checked and ...` part is there to short-circuit the `all`. If the current checkbox turns `unchecked`, then we don't need to check others. `All*` would be `unchecked`.

(**PS**: By the way, you don't need to get `.keys()` of a `dict` to iterate over keys. You can just iterate over the `dict` and it will iterate over its `keys`.)

**Edit**: Just to avoid chain reaction with `All*` checkboxes toggled by clicking any sub-checkboxes, it's necessary to change the signal for `All*` checkboxes to `clicked`, instead of `toggled`. So, the `All*` check boxes will affect other below them *only* in the case of user interaction.

In the end, your modified code will be:

```
# Connect checkbox pairs
# you just use the values
# change 'itervalues' to 'values' if you are on Python 3.x
for cbPair in cbPairs.itervalues():
    cbOne = cbPair[0][0]
    cbTwo = cbPair[1][0]
    cbOne.toggled.connect(cbTwo.setChecked)
    cbTwo.toggled.connect(cbOne.setChecked) 

# Connect allCB and allRO signals
# change 'iteritems' to 'items' if you are on Python 3.x
for key, checkboxes in allCBList.iteritems():
    for checkbox in checkboxes:
        key.clicked.connect(checkbox.setChecked)
        checkbox.toggled.connect(lambda checked, checkboxes=checkboxes, key=key: key.setChecked(checked and all(checkbox.isChecked() for checkbox in checkboxes))
```

Comment: So I tried this method, and when a sub checkbox gets checked off, the All* checkbox also gets checked off, but the chain reaction happened on the other still checked sub checkboxes as well. After the All* checkbox got checked off, the still checked sub checkboxes all got checked off, following the All* checkbox

Comment: And I wanted to thank you for helping me on this issue as well. The tool never would've come this far if it wasn't for your patience and helpful tips and tricks. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Orchainu: Oh right! :), forgot about that. Fix is easy though. We just need to make `All*` checkboxes only affect others via user manipulation. That would be `clicked` signal instead of `toggled`. I'm going to edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your checkboxes are connecting the `toggled` signal **and** toggling  their state in your connected slots so the signal is emitted again (so the slots are executed again...) and you get unpredictable results. Obviously that is not your wanted behavior. You can fix it in several ways:

- by disconnecting the signals at the beginning of the slots and connecting them again at the end
- by using some clever code that controls the re-emission of signals (I think this is what  Avari's code does in a very compact way, but I'm not completely sure)
- by using a `clicked` signal because it is not re-emitted when the checkbox state changes

Which approach you follow is up to you. The following code uses the third approach:

```
    self.cbPair = {}
    self.cbPair['0'] = (QtGui.QCheckBox('all1', parent), 
        QtGui.QCheckBox('all2', parent))
    self.cbPair['1'] = (QtGui.QCheckBox('1a', parent), 
        QtGui.QCheckBox('1b', parent))
    self.cbPair['2'] = (QtGui.QCheckBox('2a', parent), 
        QtGui.QCheckBox('2b', parent))

    for v in self.cbPair.values():
        for cb in v:
            cb.clicked.connect(self.updateCB)

def updateCB(self):
    cb = self.sender()
    is_checked = cb.isChecked()
    id = str(cb.text())
    try:
        # Update a whole column
        column = int(id[-1]) - 1
        rows = ('1', '2')
    except ValueError:
        # Update a row and the headers row
        rows = (id[0], )
        column = {'a': 1, 'b': 0}.get(id[-1])
        if not is_checked:
            for c in (0, 1):
                self.cbPair['0'][c].setChecked(is_checked)
    for r in rows:
        self.cbPair[r][column].setChecked(is_checked)
```

Note that I'm using the checkboxes text as a UID from wich row and colum values are calculated. If you want to use different text labels for your checkboxes you may need to set the UIDs as attributes to every checkbox.